# Vim autocomplete from ctags for system headers only works when popup is triggered manually

Tags: c, macos, vim, autocomplete, ctags

On OS X, I generated a set of ctags for the system includes using the following command:

```
ctags -f c -h ".h" -R --c-kinds=+p --fields=+iaS --extra=+q /usr/include
```

This was run inside of a `~/.vim/ctags/` directory, where I put all of the ctags I generate for system-wide header files (I also have stuff for ROS and CPP that I load conditionally, but that's neither here nor there).

Anyway.  The ctags file is set correctly in my .vimrc, and vim can definitely see the ctags, but for some reason the autocomplete popup will only display results from `#include`d header files if I write out the entire symbol and then start backspacing.  As an example, if I `#include <string.h>` in a project, and then I want to call `strlen()`, and I start to type `str` in to the active vim buffer, I will only get results for symbols that are currently in the vim buffer.  But, if I type out `strlen` and then start backspacing one or two characters and hit `<C-n>`, the popup menu will be populated with matches from any other included header files.

**EDIT: Turns out, if I just hit "s" then `<C-n>`, it works as well.  So the problem seems to be that it only works if the popup menu is launched manually.  Which makes me think that it's a plugin problem (see below)**

Additional information:

- `completeopt` is set to `completeopt=menuone,menu,preview,longest`
- I have [OmniCppComplete](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1520), which I suppose could be interfering with the behavior.  It is currently **not** being conditionally loaded for C++ files only. If you want me to edit and post my OmniCppComplete settings from my .vimrc, just ask.
- I also have [AutoComplPop](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1879) installed, but I haven't done anything to configure it, so it's running with its default settings.  Haven't really researched the plugin, so no idea if some of it's behavior could be interfering with the results.
- I have [AutoTag](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1343) and [TagBar](http://majutsushi.github.com/tagbar/) installed, but those should only be fiddling with the current directory's local tagfile.

I'm honestly pretty new to Vim, and I just have no idea where to start debugging this issue, whether it be with a random plugin or with my .vimrc settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vim has many specific completion mechanisms.

- `<C-n>` and `<C-p>` use many sources defined by the `complete` option. By default, they will provide completion using the current and all loaded and unloaded buffers, tags and included files. While you can usually get quite useful suggestions with these, it is a bit of a "catch-all" solution: it is not reliable at all if you work on reasonably large projects.
- `<C-x><C-]>` uses *only* tags so it *may* be a little more useful to you.
- And there are many more, see `:h ins-completion`.
- Omni completion is smarter: it typically runs a custom filetype-specific script that tries hard to provide meaningful completion. It is triggered by `<C-x><C-o>` and you can read about it in `:h ft-c-omni`. Omni completion is often a better choice when working with code.

Because you have two overlaping "auto"-completion plugins it's hard to say what completion mechanism is at work. You should disable those plugins and play around with the different completion mechanisms available to you.

Comment: The issue seems to be that AutoComplPop doesn't have a built-in behavior defined for C and C++ files, and it falls back to using `<C-x><C-u>`, whatever that does.  `<C-x><C-o>` gives back a pattern not found error when I use it in a C file, so for now I'm just disabling AutoComplPop and using `<C-n>` for minimally specific results. I'll have to do more research and experimenting.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: `<C-x><C-u>` calls a custom function which you don't have, hence the error. I use ACP too. It didn't support JavaScript either so I modified it. It's quite easy, actually, even for the noob that I was back then. See [here](https://github.com/romainl/dotvim/blob/master/bundle/autocomplpop/plugin/acp.vim#L33) and elsewhere in the same place.

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I was getting the error with `<C-x><C-o>`, though, which I'm still assuming means that there doesn't exist a function in my vim runtime that responds to the given pattern in C files.  I'll see if I can't fiddle with AutoComplPop based on configs, though. Looks pretty trivial. My only question is, how did you create the `acp#meetsForJavaScriptOmni`? Everything else I understand.

Comment: I just copied another definition that looked more or less like JS. I think it was Python or Ruby. And adapted it to my needs. Doing the same for C shouldn't be too hard, I think.

Comment: Thanks so much for all of the help.  I was able to implement a simple regex that short circuits on "." and "->", otherwise calls the omnifunc after 3 characters.  It turns out that the real issue was that the `#include`d files were being registered as Keywords, so ACP was calling the Keyword Completion on the way forward, hence the smaller result scope, but the omnifunc when I was backspacing because of the regex scoping. I changed the Keyword trigger to also use the omnifunc instead of ACP's function by setting the global variable when a C file is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have not mastered this yet, but I do think the following observation may be of help.

Vim's default auto complete which can be quite noisy, often gets in the way of what you call with `<C-x><C-o>`.  Specifically, I found myself calling up my tags based completions with `<C-x><C-o>` only to have them *replaced* with continued typing with Vim's default suggestions using my open buffers.

The suggestion of shutting off one of the plugins makes sense.  In my case the key was how to shut down Vim's default behavior.  I have seen several people (and to which I now include myself), set the length of the expression to a high number before triggering Vim's default. For me that is:

```
    let g:deoplete#auto_complete_start_length = 99
```

... this way you eliminate the default layer of completions that comes and goes regardless of the commands you intended to inform your work.

This still feels like a hack but it helps keep my work focused on the tag-based completions.

FYI: I use NVIM on a Mac.